# How can I execute a binary file located in the installation directory of my Python package (without sudo)

Tags: python, binary, installation, pip, sudo

Let's say I have a Python package structure like that:

```
top-level/
    __init__.py
    utilities.py
    myscript.py
    binaryfile
LICENSE.txt
MANIFEST.in
README.rst
setup.cfg
setup.py
```

When I installed the package it will be located in:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mypackage/
```

and the path of binary file will be:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mypackage/binaryfile
```

My question is: How can I execute this binary file that located under `/usr/local/...` **without root privileges** (without sudo) from a script located in my package.

I'm using my package as a console script so instead of using:

```
sudo mypackage
```

to run my package, I wanna use only:

```
mypackage
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to give execute permission to normal users, so running

```
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/mypackage/binaryfile
```

once should make it possible for normal users to execute it.

Comment: OMG, I could not think of it. Yes, I can give execute permission during installation time to file, thanks a lot!